# PHP: file functions (filesize, readile, unlink) don't work for file created by mysql

Tags: apache-http-server, php, mysql, lamp, download

I have the following query (apache, php-7.4.33, mysql):

```
SELECT [blah] from [blah] INTO OUTFILE $tmpfile FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I am trying to download this from the server using this code:

```
header("Pragma: public"); 
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"contacts.csv\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize( $tmpfile ));
readfile( $tmpfile );
unlink( $tmpfile );
```

I get error messages for filesize(), readfile() and unlink() and the uploaded file is empty eg:

```
PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for /tmp/contacts-25178.csv in /[blah]/index.php
```

The file exists if I go to the command line:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/contacts-25178.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 151253 Jan 24 21:29 /tmp/contacts-25178.csv
```

Can anybody explain this for me?

Comment: The user under which you execute PHP, probably lacks read permission for the file.

Comment: `/tmp` directory typically has the [sticky bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432699/what-is-the-t-letter-in-the-output-of-ls-ld-tmp) set, so you won't be able to unlink the file. Additionally, many servers have security tools like AppArmor or SELinux that provide additional restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

> -rw-r--r--

This says everyone should be able to read the file, but that only applies of they can read the path (i.e. each of the directories) where the file resides.

> /tmp/

On a Unix systems everyone usually has access to /tmp, but if you `ls -ld /tmp`, you should see something like this for the permissions:

> drwxrwxrwt

See that 't' at the end? That means [something special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit). But again, it should not *prevent* reading of the file.

So based on the information you have provided there is no reason why your PHP code can't read the file. But there are 2 other possiblities:

1. Your PHP service is running in a chroot environment - it can't reach the /tmp directory
2. There is Mandatory Access Control system preventing access. This might be SELinux on RHEL/derivatives, Apparmor on Debian and others or it could be implemented by the systemd filesystem namespace (either blocking or re-mapping). See https://serverfault.com/questions/847156/is-there-a-way-to-control-filesystem-access-with-systemd

(for completeness, I should mention facls here - but that is unlikely to apply here)

Mentioning what OS/distribution this is running on and how you sourced / deployed the PHP runtime would have cut down on the possibilites.

You can use an explicit path in SELECT...INTO OUTFILE... but bear in mind that mysqld might be restricted in a similar (or even a different maneer) as to where it can write files.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not running in a chroot environment, and I don't have SELinux running.  I have a standard Debian installation (11.8). file_exists() also reports that the file does not exist, but when I go the command line the file is there. This was working several years ago (have not used the script for a long time) - it appears that something has changed in PHP to make this happen.

Comment: I've worked around the problem by creating a directory owned by mysql and putting the temporary file in there. unlink() doesn't work because the process is owned by www-data and the file is owned by mysql. I'm using a cron job to delete the file. I assume that the problem is related to permissions. I have written a separate script which reports that the file doesn't exist, when run by the apache user. I haven't put this as an answer to my question because it is a workaround.

Comment: That was exactly what I suggested you do? If you change the mysqld umask to 002, add the mysql and php user to a common group, set the group ownership accordingly and `chmod g+s` then PHP will be able to delete the file.